# Dynamic variable to call appropriate class property inside LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to combine both methods below into one dynamic method, that calls the appropriate Property inside LINQ where clause based on the user input?
I thought about doing something like

```
var prop = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(name.ToLower()));
```

then do something like this in inside LINQ `x => x.{prop} == name` *not sure if such syntax exist*

```
public void FilterByName(string name)
{
    var data = new InfoCollection().Data;
    var result = data.Where(x => x.State == name)        
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public void FilterByCar(string car)
{
    var data = new InfoCollection().Data;
    var result = data.Where(x=> x.Car == car) 
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

switch(searchByString)
{
    case "name":
    FilterByName(name)
    break;

    case "car":
    FilterByCar(car)
    break;

    defualt:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
public void Filter(string column, string value)
{
    var data = new InfoCollection().Data;

    //get the column to filter
    PropertyInfo property = data[0].GetType().GetProperty(column);

    //filter getting dinamically the column
    var result = data.Where(x => property.GetValue(x, null) == value);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```